# An email as my name on other people's phone, iOS7 update

Tags: messages, ios

Why is my email popping up on other people's phone as my name?

Ever since I did the iOS7 update on my phone, my messages are not coming up as "sussy joes" it is now some kind of email.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind would be if messages is set (or became reset during the iOS 7 upgrade) to start new conversations from your Apple ID email instead of your phone number.

- Open Settings app
- Swipe up and tap Messages
- Tap Send & Receive
- Verify that the checkmark is next to the phone number

You'll want to watch for errors like I have below where the messages is still waiting for activation. *(That might force it to send as your Apple ID until the activation finishes.)*

[image]

Set the "Caller ID" or send as email or phone:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Messages > Send and recieve` and change your `Reached at by iMessage` settings to just your phone number.

Comment: I wonder if you need to change the "Start new conversations from:" section to preserve receiving at the email and still send as the phone? Your step should work if my guess and your guess are correct as to the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> under Contacts, select Short Name and turn it off.